# Is it possible to include special characters in a field name with Solr in schemaless mode?

Tags: solr, schemaless

I want my dynamic field names to be able to include hash characters. Is this possible when Solr is in schemaless mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. In the file solrconfig.xml I changed the following block of code

```
<processor class="solr.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="pattern">[^\w-\.]</str>
    <str name="replacement">_</str>
 </processor>
```

to

```
<processor class="solr.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="pattern">[^\w-\.\#]</str>
   <str name="replacement">_</str>
 </processor>
```

Comment: The above change will affect any other fields which uses this factory. May be you can create your own and then use it for your case.